# convert tags with similar names into particular format

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to xml  xslt.
i need to convert xml to specific format using xslt.
need to look for similar tag names and convert them into specific format
My input:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <tpso xmlns="packetware:teleprovision" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-  instance" xsi:schemaLocation="tpso.xsd">
     <rollback>true</rollback>
        <soid>000027041866009@ALL</soid>
     <purpose>CHANGE</purpose>
       <description>tpso for Element ALL Action CHANGE</description>
       <failureAction>4</failureAction>
      <executeOnDate>2013-10-07T11:22:21.000+00:00</executeOnDate>
           <priority>8</priority>
           <subscriberID>260060059948580</subscriberID>
          <subscriberDN>48727554404</subscriberDN>
         <parameters>
           <parameter>
            <name>MSISDN</name>
           <value>48727554404</value>
       </parameter>
        </parameters>
           <serviceActions>

       <serviceAction>
                  <name>usage_state</name>
                <reference/>
             <parameters>
                     <parameter>
                        <name>action</name>
                          <value>add</value>
                   </parameter>
                    <parameter>
                      <name>old</name>
                 <value/>
                   </parameter>
                     <parameter>
                       <name>new</name>
                        <value>0ghfgfg</value>
                    </parameter>
                 </parameters>
             </serviceAction>

     <serviceAction>
        <name>usage_state</name>
        <reference/>
        <parameters>
            <parameter>
                <name>action</name>
                <value>add</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <name>old</name>
                <value/>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <name>new</name>
                <value>1ghfgfg</value>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </serviceAction>

     <serviceAction>
        <name>usage_state</name>
        <reference/>
        <parameters>
            <parameter>
                <name>action</name>
                <value>add</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <name>old</name>
                <value/>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <name>new</name>
                <value>2ghfgfg</value>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </serviceAction>

     <serviceAction>
        <name>usage_state</name>
        <reference/>
        <parameters>
            <parameter>
                <name>action</name>
                <value>add</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <name>old</name>
                <value/>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <name>new</name>
                <value>3ghfgfg</value>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </serviceAction>
     <serviceAction>
        <name>usage_state</name>
        <reference/>
        <parameters>
            <parameter>
                <name>action</name>
                <value>add</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <name>old</name>
                <value/>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <name>new</name>
                <value>4ghfgfg</value>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </serviceAction>
    </serviceActions>

        </tpso>
```

Output needs to be like below

```
           "usage_state": { "0" : {"operation": "add","value" : "0ghfgfg"},
                "1" : {"operation": "add","value" : "1ghfgfg"},
                "2" : {"operation": "add","value" : "2ghfgfg"},
                "3" : {"operation": "add","value" : "3ghfgfg"},
                "4" : {"operation": "add","value" : "4ghfgfg"}}
```

i have no clue how to proceed. any help will be much appreciated.

XSLT for extracting values of unique tags
             Below is the xsl which i have written. Need to club both your part and mine now.

```
    <xsl:for-each select="/pw:tpso/pw:serviceActions/pw:serviceAction">
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="pw:parameters/pw:parameter/pw:name[string()='action']/../pw:value = 'add'">
      "<xsl:value-of select="pw:name"/>" : {"operation": "add","value" : "<xsl:value-of select="pw:parameters/pw:parameter/pw:name[string()='new']/../pw:value"/>"}
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="pw:parameters/pw:parameter/pw:name[string()='action']/../pw:value = 'del'">
      "<xsl:value-of select="pw:name"/>" : {"operation": "del","value" : "         <xsl:value-of select="pw:parameters/pw:parameter/pw:name[string()='old']/../pw:value"/>"}
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="pw:parameters/pw:parameter/pw:name[string()='action']/../pw:value = 'def'">
      "<xsl:value-of select="pw:name"/>" : {"operation": "def","value" : "<xsl:value-of select="pw:parameters/pw:parameter/pw:name[string()='new']/../pw:value"/>"}
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="pw:parameters/pw:parameter/pw:name[string()='action']/../pw:value = 'chg'">
      "<xsl:value-of select="pw:name"/>" : {"operation": "chg","newvalue" : "<xsl:value-of select="pw:parameters/pw:parameter/pw:name[string()='new']/../pw:value"/>", "oldvalue" : "<xsl:value-of select="pw:parameters/pw:parameter/pw:name[string()='old']/../pw:value"/>" }
     </xsl:when>
```

"" : {"operation": "def" ,"value" : ""}

```
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Output needs to be like below 
        "billing_model":{"operation":"del","value":"2"}
         "block_data_transfer":{"operation":"def","value":"NONE"}
         "bsg":{"operation":"del","value":""}

INput
                  
          
          true
             000027041866009@ALL
              CHANGE
            tpso for Element ALL Action CHANGE
            4
             2013-10-07T11:22:21.000+00:00
                  8
           260060059948580
           48727554404
           
             
            MSISDN
            48727554404
            
             
          
        
            usage_state
            
            
                
                    action
                    add
                
                
                    old
                    
                
                
                    new
                    0ghfgfg
                
            
              
             
            usage_state
            
            
                
                    action
                    add
                
                
                    old
                    
                
                
                    new
                    1ghfgfg
                
            
               
            
            usage_state
            
            
                
                    action
                    add
                
                
                    old
                    
                
                
                    new
                    2ghfgfg
                
            
                  
              
            usage_state
            
            
                
                    action
                    add
                
                
                    old
                    
                
                
                    new
                    3ghfgfg
                
               
                
                
            usage_state
            
            
                
                    action
                    add
                
                
                    old
                    
                
                
                    new
                    4ghfgfg
                
            
                 
                   
            block_data_transfer
            
            
                
                    action
                    def
                
                
                    old
                    NONE
                
                
                    new
                    NONE
                
            
             
             
            bsg
            
            
                
                    action
                    del
                
                
                    old
                    
                
                
                    new
                    
                
            
              
               
            billing_model
            
            
                
                    action
                    del
                
                
                    old
                    
                
                
                    new
                    2

Comment: The question is not clear: where **exactly** do the values you show in the output appear in the input?

Comment: update the output. in the output the 0,1,2,3,4 is normal sequence , operation and value are like variable names. for operation we need to get the tag value <action> and for value we need ot get the corresponding tag<value>

Comment: Ok, so what exactly is the question here?

Comment: need to convert xml into the above mentioned format using xsl. not getting any clue how todo it

Comment: Have you tryed anything so far?

Comment: no.no clue where how to do it. any hint will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a grouping problem. If you are using XSLT 1.0, then you need to read up on [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) which is generally the most efficient way of handling such problems.

I am assuming you are grouping **serviceAction** elements by their **name**, so you start off by defining a key to look up **serviceAction** elements by name

```
 <xsl:key name="service" match="t:serviceAction" use="t:name" />
```

(Note, the **t:** prefix here is because in your original XML, all the elements are in the namespace="packetware:teleprovision", and so you will need to declare this in your XSLT too. I am using the prefix **t** for the declaration in this case).

Then, to get the distinct **name** elements, which form the basis of your group, the expression is as follows:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="t:serviceActions/t:serviceAction
                             [generate-id() = generate-id(key('service', t:name)[1])]" />
```

This looks at all **serviceAction** elements, and finds the first one that occurs in the key for the value of its current **name**.

Then, to get the elements in each group, you can just iterate over the key, like so:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('service', t:name)">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:t="packetware:teleprovision">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:key name="service" match="t:serviceAction" use="t:name" />

    <xsl:variable name="quote">"</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="t:serviceActions/t:serviceAction[generate-id() = generate-id(key('service', t:name)[1])]" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="t:serviceAction">
        "<xsl:value-of select="t:name" />": <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('service', t:name)">
            <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
            "<xsl:number />" : {
                "operation": "<xsl:value-of select="t:parameters/t:parameter[t:name='action']/t:value" />",
                "value" : "<xsl:value-of select="t:parameters/t:parameter[t:name='new']/t:value" />"
            <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        }
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This outputs the following

```
    "usage_state": {
        "1" : {
            "operation": "add",
            "value" : "0ghfgfg"
        },
        "2" : {
            "operation": "add",
            "value" : "1ghfgfg"
        },
        "3" : {
            "operation": "add",
            "value" : "2ghfgfg"
        },
        "4" : {
            "operation": "add",
            "value" : "3ghfgfg"
        },
        "5" : {
            "operation": "add",
            "value" : "4ghfgfg"
        }
    }
```

Note, in XSLT 2.0, you can use [xsl:for-each-group](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1314) instead of the Muenchian grouping method, to simplify things.

Comment: "*This is an example of a grouping problem.*" I don't see anything in the question to suggest that.

Comment: @Tim C thank you. this is what i was looking for thought not exactly the same.i need to extract the unique tags as well along with the grouping of similar ones. I have added my xsl in the code section. i need to club my part with yours handling both unique tags and similar tags. any idea how to club these ones